# Declare Public Variablen and assign values - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables, public

Is there a way to declare a public variable and also assign value?

This is the code in a sub which works perfectly:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()


    Dim arrStatistics As Variant

    'Set arrStatistics
    arrStatistics = Array("H/T - Goal Scored", "H/T - Goal Conceded", "H/T - Both teams Scored", "H/T - Over 0.5", "H/T - Over 1.5", "H/T - Over 2.5", "H/T - Result" _
                , "F/T - Goal Scored", "F/T - Goal Conceded", "F/T - Both teams Scored", "F/T - Over 0.5", "F/T - Over 1.5", "F/T - Over 2.5", "F/T - Result")

End Sub
```

This is how a declare the variable to act as `Public`:

```
Public arrStatistics As Variant
```

BUT when i use this i receive an error:

```
Public arrStatistics As Variant

'Set arrStatistics
arrStatistics = Array("H/T - Goal Scored", "H/T - Goal Conceded", "H/T - Both teams Scored", "H/T - Over 0.5", "H/T - Over 1.5", "H/T - Over 2.5", "H/T - Result" _
                , "F/T - Goal Scored", "F/T - Goal Conceded", "F/T - Both teams Scored", "F/T - Over 0.5", "F/T - Over 1.5", "F/T - Over 2.5", "F/T - Result")
```

Comment: For a **non-array** value that **doesn't change** (i.e. it is *constant*ly the same value ), you can also use a `Const`, like so:  `Public Const SomeText As String = "This is a Constant!"`.  But, to reiterate, this won't work with an Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you must declare your variable public outside the procedure

```
Option Explicit

Public arrStatistics As Variant
```

And then initialize the content with a procedure.

```
Public Sub InitPublicVariabels()

    arrStatistics = Array("H/T - Goal Scored", "H/T - Goal Conceded", "H/T - Both teams Scored", "H/T - Over 0.5", "H/T - Over 1.5", "H/T - Over 2.5", "H/T - Result" _
            , "F/T - Goal Scored", "F/T - Goal Conceded", "F/T - Both teams Scored", "F/T - Over 0.5", "F/T - Over 1.5", "F/T - Over 2.5", "F/T - Result")

End Sub
```

But instead of having large data in the code it might be an option to put the data into a hidden worksheet, that you can read into the array easily. Much more convenient to edit the data, and a good practice to seperate code and data.